# Using PowerShell upload files to FTP, with file name in GB2312, not UTF-8

Tags: .net, powershell, encoding, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I was trying to write a test script to upload file to FTP. My system is Windows 7. When I use Windows Explorer to watch the FTP, all Chinese are in wrong characters. Using Firefox to watch, in GBK encoding, all files' names are correct. Now I want to upload files in GBK encoding names, so Firefox will see all names right. Here's my attempt:

```
$coder1= [system.Text.encoding]::GetEncoding('GB2312')
$coder2 = [system.Text.encoding]::UTF8

$user = "test"
$password = "test"
$ftp = 'ftp://10.10.10.253/shzx/'
$souce = '新建文本文档.txt'
$loacalfile = Get-Item w:\test\新建文本文档.txt
$souce1 = [system.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($souce,$coder1)
$encodeA = $ftp+$souce

$request = [system.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($encodeA)
$request = [system.Net.FtpWebRequest]$request
$request.Method=[system.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::uploadfile
$request.Credentials = New-Object system.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$password)
$request.UseBinary = $true
$request.UsePassive = $true

$dest = $request.GetRequestStream()
$src = [system.IO.File]::OpenRead($loacalfile)
$buffsize = [system.Math]::Min($src.length , 4096)
$buff = New-Object system.Byte[] $buffsize

$numbuffloaded = 0
$byteread = 0

do
{
   $byteread = $src.read($buff,0,$buffsize)
   $dest.write($buff,0,$buffsize)
   $numbuffloaded ++
}
while($byteread -ne 0)

$dest.close()
$src.close()

$response = $request.GetResponse()
```

And after I upload the test file, name is not correct. No matter encode in UTF8 or GBK using Firefox to watch it. I guess FTP server thinks my file name encoding is still UTF-8. So it mistakes decoding. And if I upload with UTF8 encoded name, at least FTP file name will be right when I set Firefox encode in UTF8.
Is there a way to make FTP server decoding right? Should I set `FtpWebRequest.Headers` or else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot choose encoding to be used with `FtpWebRequest`.

`FtpWebRequest` sends `OPTS utf8 on` command to the server, when starting a connection.

If the server responds positively, `FtpWebRequest` will use UTF-8. If not, `FtpWebRequest` will use local Windows legacy character set.

So all you can do it to set local legacy character set to `GB2312` (`936`?). Assuming the server responds negatively to `OPTS utf8 on`.

Comment: thanks a lot . That's how the function work. Finally I know why my work not working. I will choose another way to do this.